# Test spring boot controllers with JUnit5+Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, junit5, spring-boot-test, spring-security-rest

I have a spring boot application and want to write integration tests for controllers. It is my `SecurityConfig`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final SessionAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    private final SessionAuthenticationFilter sessionAuthenticationFilter;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     /... 
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    } 
}
```

It is my controller:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    //...

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public List<TestDto> getAll(){
        List<TestDto> tests= testService.findAll(authService.getLoggedUser().getId());
        return mapper.toTestDtos(tests);
    }
}
```

I Created a test(JUnit 5):

```
@WebMvcTest(TestController.class)
class TestControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean(name = "mockTestService")
    private TestService testService;

    @Autowired
    private TestMapper mapper;

    @MockBean(name = "mockAuthService")
    private AuthService authService;

    private Test test;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        User user = new Test();
        user.setId("userId");
        when(authService.getLoggedUser()).thenReturn(user);
        test = new Facility();
        test.setId("id");
        test.setName("name");
        when(testService.findAll("userId")).thenReturn(singletonList(test));
    }

    @Test
    void shouldReturnAllIpaFacilitiesForCurrentTenant() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/test").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$..id").value(test.getId()))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$..timeOut").value(test.getName()));
    }
}
```

When I start the test I get an exception: `Consider defining a bean of type 'com.auth.MyUserDetailsService' in your configuration.`

It happens because I have not UserDetailsService bean in the test. What should I do:

1. Add 3 beans are required for SecurityConfig, like:

   @MockBean
   MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
   @MockBean
   SessionAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
   @MockBean
   SessionAuthenticationFilter sessionAuthenticationFilter;
2. Add test implementation of SecurityConfig
3. something else

Which approach is better?

Answer (score 0):

For writing tests for your controller endpoints using `@WebMvcTest` I would use the great integration from `MockMvc` and Spring Security.

Make sure you have the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Next, you can mock the authenticated user for your `MockMvc` requests and also set the username, roles, etc.

Either use an annotation to populate the authenticated user inside the `SecurityContext` for the test:

```
@Test
@WithMockUser("youruser")
public void shouldReturnAllIpaFacilitiesForCurrentTenant() throws Exception {
   // ... 
}
```

Or use one of the `SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors`:

```
this.mockMvc
  .perform(
      post("/api/tasks")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .content("{\"taskTitle\": \"Learn MockMvc\"}")
        .with(csrf())
        .with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.user("duke"))
    )
  .andExpect(status().isCreated());
```

You can find more information on this [here](https://rieckpil.de/guide-to-testing-spring-boot-applications-with-mockmvc/).

Comment: I can not start my test, because I get an exception: Consider defining a bean of type 'com.auth.MyUserDetailsService' in your configuration. I wrote it in my question. When I start the integration test it tries to start SecurityConfig and SecurityConfig requires  MyUserDetailsService and 2 more beans